# Jinja2 {% include with context %} and globals

Tags: python, django, templates, jinja2

I'm using jinja2 and the jinja-atoms extension (more or less inclusion tags for jinja2: https://github.com/semirook/jinja-atoms) and run into a naughty problem: the atoms used inside an included template are undefined.
I dove in jinja sources and found the culprit: include with context creates a new shared context, which doesn't get the globals.

As the atoms are put in the environment globals dictionary, they are not available in the included template.

The behavior seems to be intentional though, so I get 2 questions:
1. Why would a shared context not get the globals?
2. Where else could the atoms be stored to be available in all templates?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by globals here exactly, but the previous context should persist: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#import-visibility

Comment: It should, but it does not. If you are familiar with jinja, you can check my pull request: https://github.com/qur2/jinja2/commit/26f4a1f702d568e3889156f35e848f743307ddce